# How to tell the software version under a tag on Docker hub

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am quite newbie in docker, and I am trying to find the way to tell version for a docker hub tagged image.

For instance, the `jenkins/jenkins:lts-latest` image, listed here https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags/, what image version does actually aliase? And how can I infer the correspondent dockerfile/branch in jenkins repo?

I tried with docker search but I couldn't. I tried also to find a clue in the official Jenkins github dockerfile repo: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker, but I don't see any bindung tag or anything that gives me a hint on the source of the image

Another example, I have a Kubernetes cluster, and when I check my Nexus pod, I see likewise that the image is defined as `sonatype/nexus3:latest`. 
In this case at least I have the `imageID: docker-pullable://sonatype/nexus3@sha256:434a2564aa64646464afaf..` but once again I don't know how to map it to the actual version of the software

Comment: There isn’t a universal way to get this information.  It may not even exist, if the underlying software doesn’t have “versions” _per se_ (maybe it’s a daily build or something the author built once for a demo) and/or if the Dockerfile isn’t publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the repo you asked, the answer is No.

When setup repo on dockerhub, there are two kinds of options for user to choose as follows:

**1) Create Repository:**

In this way, dockerhub just create a repo for user, and user need to build his own image on local server, tag it, and push it to dockerhub.

When user push his image to dockerhub, no additional information about the source version will be appended, so can't get any source map from dockerhub.

[jenkins/jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags/), just this kind of repo.

**2) Create Automated Build**

In this way, dockerhub will fetch the code from github or bitbucket, and build the image on its cloud infrastructure, so it will know exactly what source commit is for current docker image.

[jenkins/jnlp-slave](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jnlp-slave/tags/), just this kind of repo.

Then, you can click its [Build Details](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jnlp-slave/builds/) on the web page, click into one link, e.g. `3.26-1-alpine`, you will see log mentioned `0a0239228bf2fd26d2458a91dd507e3c564bc7d0` is the source commit.

To sum up, for the repo you mentioned in the question, they are not `Automated Build`, so you cannot get the map for the image & source code, but if you happen to find a repo in dockerhub which is `Automated Build` later & want to know the map, then you can.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand your question, you are trying to tag the docker image exact with same version as of your software version. For that I use to create image tag:

`$ export VERSION="2.31-b19"
 $ docker tag "<user>/<image>:${VERSION}" "<docker_hub_user>/<repo>:latest"`

If this is not the case. Please explain your use case a bit more so that we can provide you a better workaround.

Comment: No, I am trying the opposite. Infering whats the real version of the software  under a tag in dockerhub (without having to run the image and check version from within app itself). For instance, what version is currently jenkins/jenkins:lts-latest ?